# Duplicate Data Delete

Tags: c#

I Have two Queue and i Want To Delete Data is Duplicate and i want to insert only not duplicate in Queue 3

```
            foreach (GPJ_Model _gpjQx in gpjQx)
        {
            foreach (GPJ_Model _Model in mainP)
            {
                if (_gpjQx.dep.CompareTo(_Model.dep) != 0)
                {
                    updateP.Enqueue(_Model);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify,

```
    foreach (E e1 in q1)
    {
        foreach (E e2 in q2)
        {
            if (e1.CompareTo(e2) != 0)
            {
                q3.Enqueue(e1);
            }
        }
    }
```

What this is doing is adding to q3 all elements of q1, multiple times, once for every element in q2 that is different from that element of q1. If q1 is `[1, 2, 3]` and q2 is also `[1, 2, 3]` then q3 will have `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`.

I doubt that is what you want.

Try to describe the problem correctly, possibly using an example. In all likelihood, you will yourself figure out how to solve it then.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd optimise by building a hash-set of the existing data:

```
var existing = new HashSet<WhateverType>(_gpjQx.Select(x=>x.dep));
foreach(var item in mainP) {
    if(!existing.Contains(item.dep)) {
        updateP.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
```

(where `WhateverType` is the type of the `dep` property).

This should make things O(n+m) rather than O(n*m).

Comment: I was going to propose something like that, but the question is ambiguous: Does he also want to  remove them from the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your question is this: How to find duplicates in two queues, delete those and copy them to a new queue?

Here is a language agnostic version:

- create two sorted lists, one for each queue
- step through each queue in synch, comparing each element

  - if they are equal: remove and add to third list
  - (if multiple identical elements can be in the queues, repeat until you are looking at a new, different element)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ version

```
var distinct = gpjQx.Union(mainP).Distinct();

foreach(var value in distinct)
    updateP.Enqueue(value);
```